# Removing UIBarButtonItem FlexibleSpace from array removes all FlexibleSpace items

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uibarbuttonitem, ios11

I have a use case where I add and remove UIBarButtonItems from a UIToolbar based on certain conditions. My pre-iOS11 pattern was to hold strong references to them, and use `removeObject:` to remove them from the `toolbar.items.mutableCopy` array, then set `toolbar.items` with that mutated array.

With iOS11, `removeObject:` removes *all* of the FlexibleSpace objects from the array, not just the one that I'm holding the strong reference to. It seems like the `isEqual` method is now using a value comparison rather than a pointer comparison.

My workaround is to manually keep track of the position of the items in the array, and remove them by their index.

My question is this: Has anyone else experienced this, and is this documented anywhere? If so, what was your workaround?

Cheers!

Comment: I feel like your only options would be to manually track indices or subclass and provide your own equality or marker to identify individual objects.

Comment: Agreed! That does seem like the only option currently. However this jus feels like an undocumented regression in the OS unless I was just missing something pretty big.